# Instead of ngOnint of the app.component, where to put the api call which makes the system wait until the response is retuned & injected into the body?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, webapi

I am new to angular and trying out different things. Recently I stumbled upon an issue that needs me to take some actions based on the results being returned by the k but before anything loads in the application.

Right now I am calling a `webapi` in the kof the `app.component.ts`, and based on that I am hiding the contents in the website but recently I noticed a slow response from the server that caused a slow response from the `webapi` hence the actions that needed to be taken are delayed hence not hiding the content.

Now, instead of the of the `app.component` where I am calling the api which returns promise and then inject the result into the `css` of the body's kI need to put the api call somewhere until the result is returned the system should not proceed.

update:

ngOninit() of the app.component, we have called an api that basically returns the true/false. Based on that, 'type' a class is injected into the document.body i.e. IsVisible. And in the Sass of app.component it disables the logos and other contents in the web page.

api call

```
const res= app.services.getIsActiveType().toPromise();
document.body.ClassList.Add(res.type);
```

in sass

```
body {
  &.Type{
    logos {
      dispaly: none;     
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you use loading on template and use `*ngIf` on your content until response is generated?

Comment: @roya due to some reasons and multiple copies of the project we are told not the change anything in the html hence doing it from code.

Comment: you need to perform some code in here or `plunker`, its more understandable.

Comment: done, check the updated part of the question.

Comment: as a simple way if you can change the way api returns answer, instead of false it returns true, and in your scss you can initially set `display: none` and then visible the element. for the second choice you can use `canLoad` property of router for specific route and call your api there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for initialization before anything is displayed, you need [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER)

> A DI token that you can use to provide one or more initialization functions.
>
> The provided functions are injected at application startup and executed during app initialization. If any of these functions returns a Promise or an Observable, initialization does not complete until the Promise is resolved or the Observable is completed.
>
> You can, for example, create a factory function that loads language data or an external configuration, and provide that function to the APP_INITIALIZER token. The function is executed during the application bootstrap process, and the needed data is available on startup.

Answer (score 1):

using `canLoad` or `canActive` property of the router can help you.